# How to pass Python Output to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm relatively familiar with Python but I am new to JavaScript and Web Development.

I am trying to pass data received from Python which uses an API (more specifically SpotifyAPI) to my JavaScript file.

The Python file will retrieve the data from the API and assign the data to the variable as an integer. I would then like to use the integer value in my Javascript code to change a Javascript canvas I am working on.

I have already tried using JSON but with no success. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I feel like a much simpler solution would be to use JavaScript Spotify API.

Comment: Or you need to again expose an API to JS from Python. Are you using Django?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do here would be to learn how http calls, Ajax works in JS and then use javascript to call the API and parse the response.

But, if you have to use python, the most clean and simple way to do that would be by wrapping Spotify API with API written in python and then calling that API from your javascript program.

Example:

Python program calling Spotify API (pyspotify.py)

```
import requests
def callSpotify(api_url, *params):
    response = requests.get() / requests.post()
    
    return response.text
```

Python flask API to pass the response value to javascript function

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import pyspotify

app = Flask(__name__)

api_url = "" # Spotify api url here

@app.route("/getspotifydata)
def py_spotify():
    # prep and pass all params req
    int_val = pyspotify.callSpotify(api_url, token, *params)
    return jsonify({'int_value': int_val}
```

Now a javascript fetch to fetch the Python API to get the integer

```
fetch('http://localhost:port/getspotifydata')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Refer - https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-and-fetch-api